# How to know the user accessing my excel file in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, vba, excel, vbscript

I've been trying on how to know which is accessing my excel file.
in some cases for example if you open a word file "winword.doc" 
it will create ~$winword.doc file in which if you open in notepad it will display the current user. However this is not applicable to all.

I want to know how to check user of excel file in vb.net or vb code.

```
 Private Function CheckFile(ByVal filename As String) As Boolean
    Try
        'Check file access if can be opened
        System.IO.File.Open(filename, IO.FileMode.Open, IO.FileAccess.Read, IO.FileShare.None).Close()
        'Return CheckFile to False if File is not opened
        Return False
      Catch ex As Exception
        'If file deemed to be open Boolean is True
        Return True
    End Try
End Function
Private Function CheckIfRunning(ByVal processname As String) As Boolean
    'processname = "SLDWORKS"
    Dim CurrentSessionID As Integer = Process.GetCurrentProcess.SessionId
    Dim val As String = "no"
    For Each proc As Process In Process.GetProcesses
        If proc.SessionId = CurrentSessionID Then
            val = "yes"
        End If
    Next
    If val = "no" Then
        Return False
    Else
        Return True
    End If
End Function
 Public Sub Main()
    Dim freader As System.IO.StreamReader
    'Loop while file still opened
    Do While CheckFile("location.xls") = True
        If CheckIfRunning("EXCEL.EXE") = True Then
        Else
            MsgBox("file is not running in process. File Must be opened in another location")
        End If
        Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000)
    Loop
    End Sub
```

Hoping you could assist me on this. I want to know who access my file and who locked it.
This has a flaw if you open an excel file in your station it will always return false.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This answer](https://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/714431-get-username-if-file-already-open-2.html#post3532197) works for me, both locally and over the network with different users. I'm using Excel 2013.

I think RoryA is [Rory](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3611989/Rory) here on SO, so if he shows up I'll remove my answer in favor of his so he can get the votes he's due.

Note that this is VBA code. If/how it translates to other VB scopes, I don't know.

```
Public Function WhoHasXMLWorkbookOpen(strFile As String) As String
   Dim vFileParts

   vFileParts = VBA.Split(strFile, "\")
   vFileParts(UBound(vFileParts)) = "~$" & vFileParts(UBound(vFileParts))
   strFile = VBA.Join(vFileParts, "\")

   If CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject").FileExists(strFile) Then
      WhoHasXMLWorkbookOpen = GetFileOwner(strFile)
   End If
End Function

Public Function GetFileOwner(ByRef strFileName As String) As String
'http://www.vbsedit.com/scripts/security/ownership/scr_1386.asp
   Dim objFileSecuritySettings     As Object
   Dim objSD                       As Object
   Dim intRetVal                   As Integer

   Set objFileSecuritySettings = _
   GetObject("winmgmts:").Get("Win32_LogicalFileSecuritySetting='" & strFileName & "'")
   intRetVal = objFileSecuritySettings.GetSecurityDescriptor(objSD)

   If intRetVal = 0 Then
      GetFileOwner = objSD.Owner.Name
   Else
      GetFileOwner = "Unknown"
   End If
End Function
```

Example usage:

```
? WhoHasXMLWorkbookOpen("X:\Directory\file.xlsm")
```